# Right annotations to a list<String> JAXB

Tags: java, list, jaxb, annotations

I searched and saw many questions with similiar scanerios yet i couldnt make my solution work

I want a simple object to be converted into XML using JAXB.

My problem is i have an arrayList as one of my properties and i just cant find the right annotation to go with it.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "fighter")
public class fighter{
private int health;
private int energy;
private String name;
private List<String> abilities;
}
```

if i remove the abilities property i can marshall\unmarshall this class.

but when i try to do it with the abilities property its telling me i have illegal annotation

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "abilitiesList")
@XmlElement(name = "ability")
public List<String> getAbilities(){
return abilities
}
```

I've tried all sort of annotations but I just dont get whats wrong with it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "fighter")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Fighter{

    @XmlElement
    private int health;

    @XmlElement
    private int energy;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "abilitiesList")
    @XmlElement(name = "ability")
    private List<String> abilities;
}
```

Your getters and setters must be without JAXB annotations.

Your list of abilities will be marshalled like this :

```
<abilitiesList>
    <ability></ability>
    <ability></ability>
</abilitiesList>
```

If it's not working, please provide a sample of your expected XML.

Comment: I want the XML you wrote in addition to the other properties. i cant copy the entire class since its in my work and its internal, but i use @XmlElement above every get() method. and what i wrote above the getList one. I had only 1 illegal annotation, when i tried your solution, I removed the annotation above the get() of the list property added it on the property itself like you wrote and now i have 4 illegal annotations

Comment: The illegal annotation problems come from the XmlAccessorType. It specify that it is your field and not your getters that should be annotated. If you annote your fields instead of your getters it should work. I updated the answer.

Comment: ok after moving the XmlElement to the field i return to 1 illegal annotation, after removing the abilities property completly i still have illegal annotation. the only annotations i have are XmlElement above the regular properties, and one override on to string of the class, thats all i have. no idea what went wrong cause i manage to do that before, only adding the abilities messed it up somehow

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace of the IllegalAnnotationException ?

Comment: Ok appearntly I used ctrl+Y to bring the property back and that action removed the super constructor. i tried your solution and it worked. thx!